# problem with onclick event called for all buttons not the one that got clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an Index view where I display a list of books, and I have a partial view where I use it to display the list of books in the Index(main) view, and I have a delete button for each book displayed in the partial view so that when I click on delete it will delete the wanted book using ajax call, but what happens instead that all the books get deleted not just the one I want

the Index view looks like this

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Books>

@foreach(var item in Model){
    @await Html.PartialAsync("../Books/_BookView", item)
}
```

and inside the partial view _BookView I display a single book with its details and a delete button,
my ajax script inside _BookView looks like the following

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#deleteBook', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "@Url.Action("DeleteBook","Book")",
            data: {bookId: this.value},
            success: function () {
                alert("Deleted Successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Deleting failed");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
</head>
```

and my delete buttons looks like this

```
<button id="deleteBook" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.BookId)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Delete</button>
```

when I click any delete buttons for a book all of them gets deleted, I am aware that might be because all my buttons have the same id, is there a way to make ajax call the delete action for the book I want only(while still having dynamic buttons made in the partial view inside the foreach in the Index view), Thanks in advance.